# Fire jQuery if parent lose class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, addclass, toggleclass

I've got a simple Image-Slider (Flexslider 2 based on jQuery) on my website. If an element gets active, the element gets the class called "active-slide".

If this happen, the child  should get the class "show". If the parent lose the class, the child  should lose its class as well.

**My current script is not working:**

```
$( ".flexslider .slides li" ).change(function() {
  $( ".child" ).toggleClass("show");
});
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<ul class="flexslider">
    <li class="">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400x100">
        <div class="flax-caption">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    </li>
    <li class="active-slide">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400x100">
        <div class="flax-caption">Lorem Ipsum</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you show me your full code?

Comment: @Loading.. - I sat there for a good few seconds waiting for your username to load, then... Oh dear me. Time for coffee!

Comment: That's my only jQuery. The HTML look like that: `<ul class="flexslider"><li class=""><img src="http://www.placehold.it/400x100"><div class="flax-caption">Lorem Ipsum</div></li><li class="active-slide"><img src="http://www.placehold.it/400x100"><div class="flax-caption">Lorem Ipsum</div></li></ul>`

Comment: There is no `className` change event!

Comment: @susanloek - Instead of posting the HTML in a comment, which might be vital to your original question; could you post the code into your question, please?

Comment: The change event is limited to <input> elements, <textarea> boxes and <select> elements

Comment: during any change assuming active is a class in css and tabclcik is ui element   , $(".tabclcik").removeClass('active');
and then 
$(this).addClass('active');

Comment: @GeoffJames - I can understand that you've invested your time to see my username, but it's still loading :)

Comment: @susanloek No child of li having show class found in your HTML.

Comment: You can use one of API callbacks for Flexslider 2, `start, before, after, end, added, removed, init`. Here are [default options in source code](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/blob/master/jquery.flexslider.js#L1099)